# What is the best way to handle obsolete information in a database with a spring boot application

Tags: postgresql, sensors

I am working on an application tracking objects detected by multiple sensors. I receive my inputs by consuming a kafka message and I save the informations in a postgresql database.

An object is located in a specific location if it's last scan was detected by sensor in that exact location, example :

- Object last scanned by sensor in room 1 -> means last location known for the object is room 1

The scans are continously happening and we can set a frequency of a few seconds to a few minutes. So for an object that wasn't scanned in the last hour for example. It needs to be considered out of range.

So my question now is, how can I design a system that generates some sort of notification when a device is out of range ?
for example if the timestamp of the last detection goes longer than 5 minutes ago, it triggers a notification.

The only solution I can think of, is to create a batch that repeatedly checks for all the objects with last detection time is more than 5 minutes for example. But I am wondering if that is the right approach and I would like to ask if there is a better way.

I use kotlin and spring boot for my application.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You would need some type of heartbeat mechanism, yes.

Query all detection events with "last seen timestamp" greater than your threshold, and fire an alert when that returned result set is more than some tolerable threshold (e.g. if you are willing to accept intermittent lost devices and expect them to be found in the next scan).

As far as "where/how" to alert - up to you. Slack webhooks are a popular example. Grafana can do alerting *and* query your database.